# How to map a drive to another domain using command prompt?

Tags: vpn

How can I map a drive to another server on another domain using net use? I tried using these commands but they didn't work. Currently our company is setup with OpenVPN if this matters

```
net use H: \\servershare /user:domainuser password /persistent:yes

net use n: \\servernamesharename /user:username@domainname password

net use n: \\servernamesharename /user:domainnameusername password
```

The user is able to see the folder but could not get in and she has her VPN open
yet could not get in. I check the folder permisions in the server and everything looks ok
from our end. Currently the user is located in Mexico. Is there any other way to do
this? I would really appreciate if someone can help I already spent a couple
hours searching, but I haven't had success.

Comment: You could tell us a little more about what happens when you try the above, can she browse to the drive via explorer, etc?

Answer (score 1):

you need a \ to separate the domain & user,

e.g. DOMAIN\USER

```
net use n: \\servername\sharename /user:domainname\username password
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember that the vpn software may be blocking smb traffic, as may be the server to which you are connecting.

If the server is, say, windows 2008 and it has a firewall rule to allow smb connections from the localsubnet but not from other subnets then your connection will fail.

If you want more info you'll have to specify what you mean by 'didn't work'